# Downloading multiple files from google addon

Tags: google-apps-script, return

Hi I'm trying to download multiple files from a google folder as txt. I'm using the google script. So far my code will successfully download the first file from a folder but it stops and wont download the rest of the files in that folder. Thanks

```
function doGet() {


var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('FolderKeyHere')

var files = folder.getFiles();
   while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      Logger.log(file.getName());
      var id = file.getId(); 

     var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id);

     var string = doc.getBody().getText();

     var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
     output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
     output.setContent(string);
     output.downloadAsFile(file.getName());

     return output;

   };

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be possible like that, the `return output;` will actually "return" the app and of course exit the while loop.

I think you won't be able to loop this kind of process without user action.

You might build a small Ui that would have a button to download files one by one on each button click but I guess that's not what you are looking for.

Why not create all the files in your drive, compress all the files in a single zip file, download the zip and then delete the files and the zip from your drive ?

Slightly longer to write but -I think - the only useable workflow to get multiple files in a single download.

Comment: Ive tried to download a zip but it will only download it as a .docx whereas I want all of the files as .txt

Comment: Would it be possible to store multiple output.downloadfile and then return multiples of them?